# How do I get range in Dates instead of numerical values?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
head(df)

GMT
               MSCI ACWI        DJGlbl  Russell 1000   Russell Dev S&P GSCI Industrial 
1999-03-01 -0.0070000000  0.0020000000 -0.0010000000 -0.0150000000        -0.0100000000
1999-03-02 -0.0050352467  0.0009980040 -0.0070070070 -0.0020304569         0.0040404040
1999-03-03 -0.0020242915  0.0029910269  0.0000000000 -0.0061037640         0.0010060362
1999-03-04  0.0070993915  0.0029821074  0.0151209677 -0.0010235415         0.0050251256
1999-03-05  0.0241691843  0.0089197225  0.0218470705  0.0276639344        -0.0120000000
1999-03-08  0.0039331367  0.0039292731  0.0058309038 -0.0009970090        -0.0020242915
1999-03-09  0.0029382958  0.0000000000 -0.0028985507  0.0069860279        -0.0010141988
1999-03-10  0.0078125000  0.0088062622  0.0058139535  0.0118929633         0.0091370558
```

I did calculate rolling window covariance matrices with the code below, where the names(windowsList) achieve values that are for example $`1-60` for the first 60 days cov.matrix and $`2-61` for the next covariance matrix when the window is shifted by one day:

```
windowSize <- 60
windows <- embed(1:nrow(df), windowSize)

lapplyApproach <- function(df, windows) {

windowsList <- split(t(windows), rep(1:nrow(windows), each=ncol(windows)))

names(windowsList) <- unlist(lapply(windowsList, function(x)paste(range(x), sep="",   collapse="-")))
return(lapply(windowsList, function(x)cov(df[x, ])))
}
```

My problem is that I want to get names(windowsList) values in ranges of dates instead of numbers. In example, instead of $`1-60` I would like something like $`1999-03-01 - 1999-05-21`. I tried to make a matrix of dates and then calculate ranges between them, but did not suceed. The idea is that the names ($`1999-03-01 - 1999-05-21` and so on) will be passed to Excel as the names of the sheets. In example:

```
library("XLConnect")
hb <- loadWorkbook("stuff.xlsx", create = TRUE)
createSheet(hb, names(windowsList)) 
writeWorksheet(hb,windowsList, names(windowsList),header=TRUE)
saveWorkbook(hb)
```

Could someone kindly point me in right direction?:)
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you use `rownames(df)[range(x)]`.

```
df <- read.table(text = "MSCI_ACWI        DJGlbl  Russell_1000   Russell-Dev S&P_GSCI_Industrial 
1999-03-01 -0.0070000000  0.0020000000 -0.0010000000 -0.0150000000        -0.0100000000
1999-03-02 -0.0050352467  0.0009980040 -0.0070070070 -0.0020304569         0.0040404040
1999-03-03 -0.0020242915  0.0029910269  0.0000000000 -0.0061037640         0.0010060362
1999-03-04  0.0070993915  0.0029821074  0.0151209677 -0.0010235415         0.0050251256
1999-03-05  0.0241691843  0.0089197225  0.0218470705  0.0276639344        -0.0120000000
1999-03-08  0.0039331367  0.0039292731  0.0058309038 -0.0009970090        -0.0020242915
1999-03-09  0.0029382958  0.0000000000 -0.0028985507  0.0069860279        -0.0010141988
1999-03-10  0.0078125000  0.0088062622  0.0058139535  0.0118929633         0.0091370558", header = TRUE)

windowSize <- 6
windows <- embed(1:nrow(df), windowSize)
```

I also modified the last command of the function: `df[x, ]` did not work because `x` is a list. So, I used `df[unlist(x),]` instead.

```
lapplyApproach <- function(df, windows) {  
 windowsList <- split(t(windows), rep(1:nrow(windows), each=ncol(windows)))  
 names(windowsList) <- unlist(lapply(windowsList,
            function(x) paste(rownames(df)[range(x)], sep="",   collapse=" - ")))
 return(lapply(windowsList, function(x) cov(df[unlist(x),])))
}
```

The output:

```
lapplyApproach(df, windows)

$`1999-03-01 - 1999-03-08`
                        MSCI_ACWI        DJGlbl  Russell_1000   Russell.Dev S.P_GSCI_Industrial
MSCI_ACWI            1.307947e-04  3.004810e-05  1.155990e-04  1.552330e-04       -3.310649e-05
DJGlbl               3.004810e-05  7.696563e-06  2.547058e-05  3.607536e-05       -1.244441e-05
Russell_1000         1.155990e-04  2.547058e-05  1.176579e-04  1.195526e-04       -2.707752e-05
Russell.Dev          1.552330e-04  3.607536e-05  1.195526e-04  2.065329e-04       -3.872039e-05
S.P_GSCI_Industrial -3.310649e-05 -1.244441e-05 -2.707752e-05 -3.872039e-05        5.164804e-05

...
```

Comment: Great answer Sven! Do you maybe have an idea on how I can subset the windows matrix to only include the covariance matrices in which the last observation, used in each cov.matrix computation, is the last day in each month? I thought of something with 'grep' function...Right now I subset windows matrix manually in Excel... Or else if you have some idea on how to separate the covariance matrices in the Excel file? Because I can't manage to separate them with some space.. Best Regards